# Anyone know why code cannot insert the MongoDB by using MongoCompass, I'm sure the structure it's already correct

Tags: mongodb

I planned to insert my code by MongoDB compass but when I clicked 'Insert' button, it only appears 'Inserting Document' but nothing happened even after I clicked the 'Insert' button many times and after that I try to refresh my MongoDB compass but nothing happened and the data is not inserted.

Here's my code:

```
{
"_id": "7",
"listing_id": "677728659232692395",
"arrival_date": new ISODate("2022-11-08T14:10:30Z"),
"departure_date": new ISODate("2022-11-15T14:10:30Z"),
"name": { first_name: "Gregorius", last_name: "Agung"
},
"email": "gregorius.agung04@gmail.com",
"contact": {
    "daytime_phone": "0921970278",
    "mobile": "0917820292",
    "postal_address": {
        "door": "5",
        "floor": "12",
        "street": "Swanston",
        "suburb": "Weribee",
        "state": "Victoria",
        "country": "Australia",
        "postal_code": "3003"
    }, home_address: {
        "door": "4",
        "floor": "11",
        "street": "Swanston",
        "suburb": "Weribee",
        "state": "Victoria",
        "country": "Australia",
        "postal_code": "3003"
    }
},
"number_of_guests": 2,
"guests": [
    {
        "name": "Marvel",
        "age": 22
    },
    {
        "name": "Bryant",
        "age": 23
    }
],
"deposit_paid": {$numberDecimal: 120.01
},
"balance_due_amount": {$numberDecimal: 120.01
},
"balance_due_date": new ISODate(
"2022-11-08T14:10:30Z")
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your json is wrong. Some of the keys are not in quotes and for date insertion this is not working in compass.

I tried this and it is working

```
{
  "_id": "7",
  "listing_id": "677728659232692395",
  "arrival_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1667916630000"
    }
  },
  "departure_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1668521430000"
    }
  },
  "name": {
    "first_name": "Gregorius",
    "last_name": "Agung"
  },
  "email": "gregorius.agung04@gmail.com",
  "contact": {
    "daytime_phone": "0921970278",
    "mobile": "0917820292",
    "postal_address": {
      "door": "5",
      "floor": "12",
      "street": "Swanston",
      "suburb": "Weribee",
      "state": "Victoria",
      "country": "Australia",
      "postal_code": "3003"
    },
    "home_address": {
      "door": "4",
      "floor": "11",
      "street": "Swanston",
      "suburb": "Weribee",
      "state": "Victoria",
      "country": "Australia",
      "postal_code": "3003"
    }
  },
  "number_of_guests": 2,
  "guests": [
    {
      "name": "Marvel",
      "age": 22
    },
    {
      "name": "Bryant",
      "age": 23
    }
  ],
  "deposit_paid": {
    "$numberDecimal": "120.01"
  },
  "balance_due_amount": {
    "$numberDecimal": "120.01"
  },
  "balance_due_date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1667916630000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help, the new code structure you provided had worked successfully.